# How do I plot the columns of an $M \times N$ matrix as separate lines on the same graph using ListLinePlot?

Tags: plotting, matrix

I have seen many examples that show how to plot several functions on the same graph using `ListLinePlot` is this manner:

e.g. `ListLinePlot[{data1, data2}]`.

In my case, I have an $M \times N$ matrix, for example $8192 \times 12$, stored in a single variable called `myMatrix`. Is there a simple way to pass `myMatrix` to `ListLinePlot` so that each $8192 \times 1$ "column vector" is plotted as a distinct line on the same plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference: [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)

```
ListLinePlot[{myMatrix[[All,1]],myMatrix[[All,2]], ...}]

data = {{1, 5, 10}, {1, 5, 10}, {1, 5, 10}, {1, 5, 10}, {1, 5, 10}};
ListLinePlot[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2]], data[[All, 3]]}]]
```

[image]

**Or for a compact, universal solution (Courtesy of J.M.)**

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[myMatrix]]
```

Comment: `ListLinePlot[Transpose[data]]` is more compact.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you